# An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android

I have connected live server with android application but when i click submit button create account then Application stop working. and following `exceptions` comes

How to resolve this...

here is the code i use

```
public void InsertData(final String name, final String email, final String password, final String con_password) {

        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String NameHolder = name;
                String EmailHolder = email;
                String PasswordHolder = password;
                String ConPasswordHolder = con_password;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", NameHolder));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", EmailHolder));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", PasswordHolder));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("con_password", ConPasswordHolder));


                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("198.96.95.58");


                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "Data Inserted Successfully";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(Create_account.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, email, password, con_password);
    }
```

**Error:** these exceptions comes when i click create account button.. a black screen come after clicking create account button when i debug my app.. result is here.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.myapplication1, PID: 15651
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;
        at com.example.myapplication1.Create_account$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(Create_account.java:80)
        at com.example.myapplication1.Create_account$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(Create_account.java:69)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication1-dD2mzqj0Giijo0j___OG8A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication1-dD2mzqj0Giijo0j___OG8A==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.example.myapplication1.Create_account$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(Create_account.java:80) 
        at com.example.myapplication1.Create_account$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(Create_account.java:69) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: add the code that you tried

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: I have added the code.. An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Comment: what's error did you get. pls post your error logs.

Comment: `following exceptions` you didn't show any

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.myapplication1, PID: 15651
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)

Comment: that's not full stacktrace. Show full stacktrace, and don;t add it to the comment, add it to the question.

Comment: Full stacktrace add in post

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException : Didn't find class "org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair"` Apache HTTP components have been removed from Android SDK starting from API 23 (Android 6). See the changelog: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes

Comment: ok thank you so much let me check :)

Answer (score 1):

To continue using the `Apache HTTP client`, apps that target Android 9 and above can add the following  line inside the `application tag` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

> Note: The android:required="false" attribute is required for apps that have a minimum SDK of 23 or lower, because on devices with API levels lower than 24, the org.apache.http.legacy library is not available. (On those devices, the Apache HTTP classes are available on the bootclasspath.)

See official documents about that https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28

Comment: import android.annotation.MainTherd;
import android.annotation.Nullable;
import android.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
import android.annotation.WorkerThread;

these import shows could not found symbol unSupportedAppUsage, could not found symbol WorkerThread, could not found symbol MainThread, etc